# How to make a onEdit function in Apps Script tab-specific

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a worksheet in which I want to be able to track the time & date of the last modification of the different lines. The code below (very simple) works, but it tracks all changes on the lines in the worksheet, not just from the active tab (which I want to track) but from all tabs in the worksheet.

Example: I want to track the changes in all lines of the first tab called 'Sheet1', which the code below does. However, if I make a change on line 5 in the second tab 'Sheet2', the "modified on" data in Sheet1 also gets changed, which I don't want.

With the function below, the "modified on" data gets written in column 'I' on Sheet1 of my worksheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  
  const sh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  sh.getRange ('I' + e.range.rowStart).setValue (new Date()).setNumberFormat ('DD/mm/yyyy HH:MM')

}
```

I know activity can be tracked in Excel and Sheets, but this functionality gets blocked by my organisation, hence the little code. I tried searching for the solution to my problem on this site and in youtube tutorials, no luck so far...

(I'm obviously not a programmer if that wasn't clear yet :p)

I tried to work without making a variable, but that made the code crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of limiting the onEdit trigger to only work if the edit is made on Sheet1.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if( sheet.getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),9).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("DD/mm/yyyy HH:MM");
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err);
  }
}
```